# Current across Wien bridge

Tags: homework, wien-bridge

I am trying to answer the question

> If you connect a detector between Va and Vb, knowing that the frequency to which the bridge is balanced is 6820,58Hz, what is the current that passes through the detector if the frequency goes off by 1%?

My attempt:

If I find the thevenin equivalent of the circuit then it should be straightforward. However the expressions that I end up with are:

$$
Z_{eq}=\frac{R_3(1+j\omega R_1C_1)}{j\omega C_1R_3+(1+j\omega R_3C_3)(1+j\omega R1C_1)}+\frac{R_2R_4}{R_2+R_4} 
$$

$$
V_{eq}=\bigg(\frac{j\omega R_3C_1}{1+j\omega(R_3C_3+C_1R_1+C1R_3)+(j\omega)^2C_1R_1C_3R_3}-\frac{R_4}{R_4+R_2}\bigg)V_{in}
$$

But dividing these equations so as to get the current seems like going for the hardest and most tiresome way. Surely there has to be a far simpler and straightforward way that I am missing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOazw0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Current goes **through.**  Voltage is **across.**

Comment: Current flow needs to be kept to a minimum as it would upsets the balance.
Voltage should be read with a high impedance device.

Comment: Yes, but I can't see how that would help me. Even considering a really high impedance load, the treatment is the same, how could I escape those hideous expressions?

Comment: Can you work with vectors?

Comment: I think so, I could put everything in phasors but I still get really tiresome calculations. I'm wondering if there is a slicker way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to redo your process, these are the steps for analyzing an RLC circuit, note that this kind of analysis is only valid for circuits in a "Steady State", this means that the circuit is on a state where it has had enough time to stabilize, hence the mane "Steady State Circuit Analysis".

**Step 1: Convert your circuit into phasor domain.**

> XC = 1/(j * omega * c).
>
> omega = 2*pi*f.

- Vin = (Vin < theta)
- XR1 = 22k Ω = (22k < 0º)
- XR2 = 3k Ω = (3k < 0º)
- XR3 = 11k Ω = (11k < 0º)
- XR4 = 1k Ω = (1k < 0º)
- XC1 = - j97.74k Ω = (97.74k < -90º)
- XC3 = - j97.74 Ω = (97.74 < -90º)

**Step 2: Simplify your circuit.**

- Xeq1 = XR1 + XC1 = 22k - j97.74k = (100.185 < -77.31º)
- Xeq2 = (R3*XC1)/(R3+XC1) = 20.94k - 4.713k = (21.46k < -77.31)

**Step 2: Solve for Va and Vb.**

- Va = Vin * (Xeq2/(Xeq1+Xeq2))
- Vb = Vin * (R4/(R2+R4))

**Step 3: Write an equation for the current load**

- ILoad = (Va-Vb) / XLoad

This current is supposed to be going from a to b, but if the sign is negative it means that the current is actually flowing from b to a.

Now this is the current at the frequency you actually gave, now redo steps 1,2, and 3, changing the frequency up 1% and down 1%.